# Can we have a "Feature x glitches out" duplicate target for all Pokemon Go performance problem questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, pokemon

Over the last few days I have noticed people asking questions in the following form:

> I tried to do feature x, but it glitched out.

or

> I tried to do y, but it never loads.

Pretty much all of these questions can be answered by:

> Pokemon Go is experiencing overloaded servers. While the servers are overloaded, features will randomly stop working or will take forever to load. Try again in a few hours.

---

I do not own Pokemon Go, and I do not feel I am qualified to make a good dupe-target for all of these performance related questions, as I am not familiar with the interface of the game. I also think that it hurts Arqade in the long run to keep these low-quality questions around, letting them acquire equally low-quality "I have this problem too" answers, as they represent mostly how Q&A should not be done.

Could someone create a good question that addresses all symptoms of overloaded Pokemon Go servers, so we can dupe-close all these questions without having to look around for a similar low quality question that had the same symptoms?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good idea. Closing a question as a duplicate is meant to be done when the *questions* are duplicates, not when the answers are duplicates.

Among other things, this causes a problem where the close voters need to know and be sure that the answer is indeed "the servers are overloaded" and not some other possible reason for failure. We shouldn't bake answers into a close reason.

But, if the questions themselves are indeed duplicates, by all means close them as such.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but we did end up creating a canonical question for the most common server load issues that Pokemon Go/Niantic faced:

[I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/274535/28182)

If you find any more, feel free to flag as a duplicate of that.